# flatlist extends out of the screen

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a screen that looks like this:

```
return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaViewContainer}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
       ....
        <View style={styles.listContainer}>
          {data && showFlatList !== null && (
            <UsersFoundList
              data={data}
            />
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

  listContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    //marginBottom: 50,
  },
```

I call a FlatList here from the UserFoundList component:

```
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={data.user}
        horizontal={false}
        scrollEnabled
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <UserFoundEntry user={item} onSendRequest={onSendRequest} />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item?.id?.toString()}
        ListEmptyComponent={NoUsersFoundTextBox}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

But the list overlaps with the safeAreaView at the bottom. While scrolling, it should appear from behind/under the SafeAreaView and not form top of it.
[image]

Comment: can you provide the styling for list Container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `flex: 1` in the listContainer styling, this should make it stay in the boundaries of your parent view.